# Can not connect to localhost Server via MS Sql Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I've wanted to create a local Db. So I wanted to connect to my localhost but it's not possible, when I use Windows-Authentification. "Login failed fo user ArzueAD\UserName@doamin.ch", but I don't get why. Are there any points I'm missing? As the Servername I've tried using just "localhost" and "computername\localhost".

I've even tried to select both of the Servers on my DB Engine when searching for a db, but still doesn't work:

[image]

Does anyone have any inputs?

Comment: What user did you use to install SQL Server?  What Authorisation method did you choose?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I used Windows-Authentification Method. I also deinstalled and reinstalled it, so im sure I'm installing it on the right user... saldy still no connection available....